# alignment issue with input append bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a btn-group that gives me an editable combox box. The only problem is that it's not aligned properly.

Here is the current box-

[image]

```
<div class="input-append btn-group form-control">
  <input class="input-sm span2" id="errorcount" size="16" type="text" value="Error">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>less than 1,000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>1,000 - 5,000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil">                        
  </ul>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

New changes

[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="errorcount" size="" value="Error">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>less than 1,000</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>1,000 - 5,000</a></li>

                            </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a few container classes such as `form-control` and `input-group`.

Here's a working example of your code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="errorcount" size="16" value="Error">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>less than 1,000</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>1,000 - 5,000</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5g6c281b/

Comment: It works perfect, the only issue is its very long even after adding input-sm.

Comment: Just put it inside of a container div with the size you want. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/36e5ju38/1/

Comment: Thanks Kodie...but still I have this issue, this component is part of a html table and I have added the  mockup

Comment: @user1050619 If you can put the full table in a jsfiddle I could better help you.

Comment: hmmm, well I'm guessing that it has something to do with it being inside of a table cell. I was able to fix it with kind of a hacky solution by adding `style="width:calc(100% - 34px);"` to the text field.

Comment: Also changing the text-field class back to `form-control` instead of `input-sm`

Comment: THanks much. It works fine after adding form-control and style attribute.